# Advantages of passing std::intializer_list and to have overloads with it

Tags: c++, stdinitializerlist

**Code example to have some context:**

```
#include <vector>

class DatasetValue
{
public:
    using ValueType = int;
    using Values = std::vector<ValueType>;

    DatasetValue(Values values)
        : m_values{std::move(values)}
    {

    }

    const Values &values() const
    {
        return m_values;
    }

private:
    Values m_values;
};

int main()
{
    using Dataset = std::vector<DatasetValue>;

    auto dataset = Dataset{
        {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
        {{7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}},
        {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}},
        {{3, 2, 1}},
        {{1}},
        {{ 4, 3, 2, 1}}
    };
}
```

So, we have some `Dataset` object that usually will be initialized with some predefined values on  application startup and it works good.

However, then I've changed constructor parameter type to `std::initilizer_list` and noticed that size of generated binary is reduced by **~1 KB** (in my environment, `ARM Cortext M4` target). Considering that `DatasetValue` won't be initiliezed by `lvalue`s or `rvalue`s of `containter_type` now its constructor looks like:

```
DatasetValue(std::initializer_list<ValueType> values)
  : m_values{values} {}
```

We also can see something similiar on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/b5jbhfc9W)

So, my questions is:

**Is it a good idea trying to provide constructor overloads that take `std::initializer_list`
with/instead of (depending on context) lvalue or rvalue of `container_type` ones?**

Notes:

- Haven't tried it yet, but I'm interested in if this also give us some benefits with other containters (list, map, etc.). Will be happy to know your thoughts)
- **Update:** Tests were done with no optiomization enabled (see comments)

Comment: I think your question is largely a matter of opinion (even if you were to re-phrase some of it). But, without the second c'tor, I guess each `std::vector` in your list has to be constructed, then copied/moved to/from the arguments. The `std::initializer_list` is designed pretty much *specifically* to avoid this sort of thing: As [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) says, *...a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects...*

Comment: The buzzword in that cppreference quote is "lightweight".

Comment: @AdrianMole you're right and I more or less understand why I have such result. The question is more to get some best practises or expirience from other people or even some description of disadvantages using such solution. Anyway, I believe it can be answered in some cocnreate way.

Comment: You're looking at unoptimised sizes, enabling optimisations will probably remove some/all of the difference

Comment: @AlanBirtles you're right too. I've just tried to compare sizes on O1 and there is really no difference in terms of binary size. Version `std::initializer_list` uses even 88 bytes more compared to pass by value + std::move one)
So, in other words, it has not so much sense to provide overloads that take `std::initializer_list`. Thanks, good point